# Memory efficient collections in java

Tags: java, collections, heap-memory, gigaspaces

Our application is a gigaspace based solution, which basically reads from multiple flat files and stores the data in a object. Now flat files basically contain some shipment details. So we have multiple files

1. Dockyard Details
2. Container details
3. Shipment Details
4. etc.

Now we have `Dockyard` as a parent object under which there can many objects of shipment details. We currently use an `ArrayList` to maintain shipment details for almost 50k dockyard detail objects. Current volume of data suggests that for each `Dockyard` object we will have to maintain around 1500 shipment detail object and there will almost 50k dockyard object lying in heap. Our current heap is 8GB.

So wanted to know if ArrayList is the best way to keep so many object. I have looked for other APIs as well  like `trove`, `HPPC` but they mostly offer benefits when it comes to primitive collection. Ours will be a collection of Objects. So other than increasing heap size. can someone suggest any other better alternatives.

Comment: when the size of data is so big, keeping the data in app's memory is never a good idea.

Comment: I agree on that, but we were not expecting this much of data initially, so in-memory data grid seemed a fast and good solution and backtracking , changing design would be a quite big challenge for us, as we are close to UAT testing.

Comment: You better figure something else out very quickly. If you didn't expect this much data initially, how do you think things will be 6 months from now. Your implementation simply won't scale.

Comment: Yes we are actively looking for other alternatives also, but wanted to know if there is any api which could help us out in this situation which can store this many objects with low memory footprint.

Comment: There's no collection more compact than `ArrayList`. It's just an array of object references (pointers). As for alternatives, that's too broad a question, but some kind of database, SQL or NOSQL, would be better.

Comment: Yes it's a too broad question. As I frequently work with in-memory database much bigger, I disagree with the conclusion "use a database". In my opinion, in-memory computing is inherently not easy, so it's not my first choice :-) But it can be a good design if you need very low latency for example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to keep all you objects on the heap.  With Chronicle Map for example, you can keep all the objects off heap and since they are memory mapped files, they don't even have to be in memory.  You might find you can reduce your heap size if the bulk of your data is off heap.

> there will almost 50k dockyard object lying in heap.

This is not a lot of objects. Even if each object uses 1 KB, then you are only using a 50 MB.  If you object are much bigger than this, it highly likely you should look at ways to reduce the size of the individual objects.

When we use primitive based collections it is mostly to avoid the object header for each element.  This saves 8 - 16 bytes per entry or up to 800 KB in you case.

However if you objects are 1 KB to 100 KB as you suggest, you might be able to halve the size they use in memory by restructuring them or using different data types.

BTW a 1 GB is worth about an hour of your time. I would explore doubling the memory size before spending too much time on this.